# What does return SELECT when couldn't find the value it's searching for (in SQL)?

Tags: python, sql, database, select, cs50

I'm doing an exercise where I need to update some values in a table of SQL DB via python and I can't find out what SELECT return if "user" AND another "X-condition" are NOT found in the database.

I read in another thread SELECT should return an empty set, but I still got a problem with it!

When I run:

```
example = db.execute("SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE user=:user AND X=:Y", user=user, X=Y)
```

and I try with a condition like

```
if example == {}:
    db.execute("INSERT [...]")
```

I never go inside this condition to do the INSERT stuff when the set is empty.

I found another route to solve this (write below), but is it valid at all?

```
if not example:
    do the job
```

EDIT: I'm using sqlite3!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sqlite3.html), the `execute` method always returns a Cursor which you can use to fetch the result rows, if there were any. It doesn't matter what kind of query you were doing.

If the first result you fetch is None right away, there weren't any rows returned:

```py
if example.fetchone() is None:
    db.execute("INSERT [...]")
```

Alternatively, you could fetch all rows as a list, and compare that against the empty list:

```py
if example.fetchall() == []:
    db.execute("INSERT [...]")
```

Comment: You somehow answered my question!

I got:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`

and if I try with 

`if example == []`

it goes like a charm! It's an empty list, not an empty set!

Comment: If your `example` is a list, you probably weren't using the module I was thinking of... but I'm glad that you figured it out anyway!

Comment: I'm still learning and I have no idea why it's a list to be honest! Thank you alot for your help tho!

Comment: EDIT: maybe because i'm using the SQL library from cs50 course :)